# Custom LoopBack Model with Created/Modified

Tags: api, loopbackjs, strongloop

It looks like the built in LoopBack models are baked with "create/modified" date fields. Is there an easy way to add this to "generated" models?  I've been looking through the docs but can't find anything in the model docs- http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+models

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in way ATM. I suggest using an operation hook mixed with `new Date()`. See http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks#Operationhooks-beforesave.

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure this is what you are looking for: https://github.com/clarkbw/loopback-ds-timestamp-mixin

Comment: Very nice, this looks like a better approach than what I'm currently doing, thanks!